# Why is there glow around lights in every photo shot with my Canon EF 28-70mm f/2.8 L USM Lens?

Tags: lens, canon, troubleshooting, artifacts, lens-flare

One day after using my Canon EF 28-70mm f/2.8 L USM Lens, I noticed that every photo has a huge amount of glow in the dark areas near any light area.

I tested my other four lenses to figure out if it's the lens's or camera body's fault. The other four lenses work fine without the glow problem.

I examined the problematic lens, and there seems no visible dust (observing front and back side of the lens).

Here's an example:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Comment: I just want to be sure: do you have a protective filter on that nice lens?

Comment: What aperture did you shoot this at and were the other lenses as fast?

Comment: I'd check to make sure that there weren't any grease 'smears' on the front or back elements. It's also possible, I suppose, that there could have been some internal condensation. Looks like the picture was taken someplace warm... Any trips to hotter/colder climates recently?

Comment: Maybe condensation/fog on the front or rear elements?

Comment: @mattdm : yes there is always a protective filter ( the result is the same with and without the filter )

Comment: @Robin : does the aperture value matter ? i've tested any value !
my all lenses are 2.8, and the work perfectly

Comment: @BobT : as i mentioned , front and back sides are very clean ! i suspected about internal condensation, but if it was so, it would go away since 6 months passed, but no, the result is the same ! the day this photo was shot - it was 28 deg. Celsius!

Comment: @cadmium : no , i examined very carefully, even comparing with an identical one of a friend of mine, and they are just identical, i'm getting crazy :(

Comment: If it's doing this with the filter off (and with everything else seeming good as everyone has said) send it in for repair. I'm a bit surprised, though, because the filter seemed the most likely offender. I'd double-check the result without the filter if you haven't already. If you have, time for the repair center.

Comment: yes i'm afraid that's the next move ! nothing else to check !

Comment: Actually you said that there was no *dust* on the front and rear elements. My comment was about grease smears, which may not be as apparent as dust.

Comment: Since you have a friend with the same lens... if it's exactly the same can you do some tests under controlled conditions?  Maybe a test shot of some fairy-lights?  My money's on it being the lens design but if it's fixable so much the better for you.  :)

Comment: @BobT : the lens is very clean ! no dust, no grease smears !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it isn't a condensation issue, and it is repeatable, it's time to send the lens to Canon for repair.

Comment: If you just stepped out of an air conditioned room you might have some short term condensation issue that creates these halos.

Comment: i guess that's what i'm going to do next ! but i kind of don't trust this services.

Comment: You don't trust the company that MADE the lens?

Comment: of course i trust the company that made the lens, but here in Greece the service employees are a bit far from the service idea !
... if i was in Japan, now that's a totally different thing.

Answer (score 3):

the center doublet has some cement that gets cloudy when it breaks down.  you need to find an independent repair shop that has a donor doublet that they can replace it with.  its a common design flaw of the 28-70 2.8.  repair should cost you $300-350.  i had the same problem with the same lens.  its not fungus.  canon wont replace, as they dont carry spare parts anymore.  time to make some phone calls.